# Magento 2 : How to make a Admin form without UI-Component

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform

I want to make an admin form in magento 2 without using ui component method. Please refer me a link or a appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

i will share two below link for without UI component related so please check it.

https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-create-admin-grid-and-form-without-ui-component-in-magento-2/

https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-admin-grid-and-form-without-ui-component/

I hope that is helpfully for you. so please accept my answer and upvote me.

Comment: i have try both of these but form is not display at the end

Comment: https://code.vky.co.in/magento-2-module-creator/

above link generated your module. after download install your project.

Comment: after add your module please apply all commands for magento module install related.

sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated

Comment: my discord id = mohit_gento so please chat with me I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i am following the below link for all steps after checking my module It is working so please check my screenshot.

https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-admin-grid-and-form-without-ui-component/

[image]
[image]
[image]

after apply below commands.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

if have any issues so please tell me.

Comment: thanks mohit it works

Comment: ok, @Afnan Ahmad. please accept my answer and upvote me.